# How does cold fusion work?

Tags: cold-fusion

I understand that in regular fusion, you use high levels of heat to accelerate atoms to speeds high enough to overcome nuclear force.  What method would be used to achieve [cold fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_fusion_%28disambiguation%29)?

Comment: If we knew what method would be used to achieve cold fusion, we would have cold fusion power by now.  Such a method, if it exists, is beyond our current knowledge and/or abilities.

Comment: RonM [has a theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/why-is-cold-fusion-considered-bogus?). I don't have the background to fully evaluate it, so I can't say for sure if it is worth considering. My big question about it is: does it give a hint why it is hard to reliably build cells that work and stay working? (Or has someone solved that already?)

Comment: please note that it is not the nuclear force that has to be overcome, that is attractive. It is the coulomb barrier of positive nucleus against positive nucleus

Comment: Cold fusion theory is what Ben Goldacre would call "physics-wu".  The so-called concepts in the answers below make string theory look as solid as Newton's Laws.  Don't waste your time here.  You'll be better off designing a "zero-point module."

Comment: This question has been flagged by anonymous users as _too broad_ and _primarily opinion-based._ I'm closing it _as a duplicate,_ not because it is necessarily an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

When [cold fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_fusion) hit the physics news in 1989 all the physicists in my institute followed it avidly and some tried to reproduce it. I have been following the news of cold fusion trying to keep an open mind after the disappointment of the next years.

The basic idea of all the experimental setups I have read about is to use the crystal structure of specific solids . In crystals the nuclei and electrons can have collective wave functions  that have probabilities of *electrons* and *nuclei* to exist all over the lattice. The hope of what is now called "low energy nuclear physics, LENR"  is that the coulomb barrier that will not allow a nucleus close to a nucleus can be thus defeated collectively, and the nuclei get close enough to produce fusion under certain conditions.

The problems have been  that the experiments can not be consistently reproduced, and the attention of the physics community has been removed because of this disappointment. On the other hand a number of commercial enterprises have sprung up  trying to create units of cold fusion .  When/if  If/when a commercial unit appears the specific physical model  will not be long in appearing.

Comment: "When/if If/when a commercial unit appears the specific physical model will not be long in appearing" do you mean that there are several quite sound models (aside from enough uncertainty about what conditions CF that they're not yet falsified) out there such that experimental observations will readily tell them apart?

Comment: No, I mean that first the process has to be well observed and described experimentally, so that it is repeatable and consistent in energy output. Then the theory will be found. It is a new phenomenon, if verified by a number of independent experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the method to make cold fusion work is the same as hot fusion: "you use high levels of heat to accelerate atoms to speeds high enough to overcome nuclear force".

You can make cold fusion work as follows. If you strip the electron off hydrogen atom, and let the proton capture a muon instead, then you have particle identical to the electron (as far as the Dirac equation description is concerned) aside from being 207 times heavier than the elctron and described by the Dirac equation with a central inverse square potential. So all the orbitals are the same shape and the whole thing looks exactly like a neutral Hydrogen atom aside from being 207 times smaller (the [Bohr radius normalising the solution co-ordinates shrinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom)). Actually, the first quantised Dirac equation is getting a bit inaccurate as the muon is not so negligible in mass as the electron compared to the proton, and so you really have to do this problem as a quantum two-body problem and account for the non-fixed proton. But the basic idea stays the same: we've radically shrunken the "atom".

So now, with the proton's electric charge shielded by the much tighter muon orbital, it is found that room temperature kinetic energies are enough to overcome the coulombic repulsion, and cold fusion happens.

The only catch is that we need to have a source of muons and a factory for making shrunken hydrogen and this expends a great deal more energy than we get back from fusion. But I understand that putatively workable (and so far not successful) cold fusion schemes use roughly the same idea: the idea is to catalyse the reaction by getting the hydrogen's electron orbital to shrink somehow by combining it with something else and thus allow smaller energies in overcoming Coulombic repulsion. As dmckee points out, user [Ron Maimon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon) has a theory:

> RonM has a [theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13734/26076). I don't have the background to fully evaluate it, so I can't say for sure if it is worth considering. My big question about it is: does it give a hint why it is hard to reliably build cells that work and stay working? (Or has someone solved that already?)

I have read, although don't ask for details, that a tiny amount of cold fusion happens when peeling stickytape. It's simply that the number of events is too tiny to be of any energy production good.

Comment: @RonMaimon 's qualitative theory treats the systems as semi-free, does not really consider the QM conditions in a crystal until he does his energy estimates. Lattices have surprising properties, not only bands of electrons shared over the whole. For example a high energy muon can go through the axis of a crystal lattice without interacting electromagnetically at all and retaining its energy. This has been used in proposals for muon accelerators, bending the muons by bending the crystal axis. In my books this means that a total wavefunction exists which allows this highly probable penetration.